# Http to Https redirect for wordpress on heroku

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, heroku

I'm trying to redirect all webpages to https for my wordpress app which is hosted on heroku. I'm using the Wordpress HTTPS plugin, and I've succeeded in getting all the wordpress pages to redirect to https, but my custom pages do not redirect. The app is setup using this [template](https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku). It seems like people traditionally do this by editing the .htaccess file (for example [here](https://www.letuslook.org/linux/redirect-http-to-https/)), but I can't seem to get that to work. I also tried adding '/' to the HTTPS plugin URL filters, but this didn't work either. All my attempts to add php code to the actual page just ends up in an infinite redirect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the thing that was getting me was the order in htaccess. Everything works now and my file looks like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

It was important to put the https rule first, which I hadn't done originally.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This checks to see if `https` is not on (so if it is off) then redirect the request to `https`

Comment: This doesn't work because it causes and redirect loop (perhaps because of heroku?) I found that if I changed the second line to "RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https" it works for mysite.com, but doesn't redirect for mysite.com/something