# Wordpress Ninja Forms, Access-Control-Allow-Origin and admin-ajax.php

Tags: wordpress, heroku, http-status-code-503, ninja-forms, admin-ajax

So, I have this WP installed on Heroku and I've installed Ninja forms to it. Despite everything working OK locally, when I push it to Heroku, the form is not submited and I receive this error through the Chrome's Console:

```
Failed to load https://ratts.com.br/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'http://ratts.com.br' is therefore not allowed 
access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

It's worthy to mention that this error is only delivered when I access the page via `http`, but when I access the page trough `https` the form works just fine, due to what I think to be a `CORS` problem. Anyone has any idea about how can I solve this issue? It have been three days of unsuccessful research already... rsrs

Comment: Could you forward/redirect all http requests to the https counterpart? But it seems that the http version of the site is posting to the https version or vice versa. I would try to disable the http version of the site - or make the site name/title include the https if it doesn't already. Hope you can get it resolved.

Comment: *“The response had HTTP status code 503.”* simply indicates “Service unavailable”. It seems like that’s the actual problem you need to identify the cause of and fix. The fact there’s no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in that response actually isn’t important, because the server is telling you there is some fatal error—some server-side failure—that prevents the server from proceeding further at all. (Many or most servers won’t add the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header to 5xx or 4xx error responses—instead they only add that header to 2xx success responses.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that http to https for the same domain is still considered CORS. You need to make sure all traffic is redirected from http to https. [Take a look at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831214/http-to-https-redirect-for-wordpress-on-heroku).